# Is this method is allowed to calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^2)^{\cot^2x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I was wondering if is it allow to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^2)^{\cot^2x}$ as the same technique presented here [Limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\ln x}x\right)^{1/x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306161/limit-lim-x-to-infty-left-frac-ln-xx-right1-x?noredirect=1)

meaning, $$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+x^2)^{\cot^2x}=\lim_{x\to 0}e^{ln((1+x^2)^{\cot^2x}}$$ and than calculating$\quad$  $\lim_{x\to 0}ln((1+x^2)^{\cot^2x})$.

I am asking that because I saw in some exam that a student used that method and lost all the scores. So I was wondering if it is ok and if not, why is that?

Comment: Seems OK to me, since the argument of the logarithm is always positive.

Comment: Seems totally acceptable.Infact every limits question of the form 1 to the power infinty I remember had a solution using this method.

Answer (score 1):

*This is just a personal opinion.*

For such a problem, I do prefer the following steps which allow to get more than the limit itself.

$$y=(1+x^2)^{\cot^2(x)}\implies \log(y)={\cot^2(x)}\log(1+x^2)$$ Now, using Taylor series for each piece (one at the time) and binomila expansion
$$\cot(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^3}{45}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
$$\cot^2(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{3}+\frac{x^2}{15}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$\log(1+x^2)=x^2-\frac{x^4}{2}+O\left(x^6\right)$$
$$\log(y)=1-\frac{7 x^2}{6}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=e-\frac{7 e x^2}{6}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ which, for sure, shows the limit and also how it is approached.